# Pgpool failing to connect to standby postgres server

Tags: postgresql, postgis, pgpool

I'm working on a postgresql HA setup and running into an issue with pgpool.  I'm using built in postgres streaming replication and pgpool to monitor the cluster and initiate the failover process.  Pgpool has no trouble connecting to the master server; however, it will not connect to the standby.  This is the pgpool log on boot when it finds the master first:

```
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:19999
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::19999
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3 (tataraboshi)
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0  
2021-12-29 16:40:31: pid 13221: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
```

And after shutting down the master:

```
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  setting backend node 0 status to NODE DOWN
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host 192.168.2.114(5432)
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failover: no valid backends node found
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  Restart all children
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  execute command: /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/failover.sh 0 0 "" ""
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13335: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 3

+ FALLING_NODE=0
+ OLDPRIMARY_NODE=0
+ NEW_PRIMARY=
+ PGDATA=
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ su postgres -c 'ssh -T postgres@ touch /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/failover.trigger'
```

And then it hangs on the script due to the missing parameters.  This happens no matter which server is the master.  Also, sometimes on boot pgpool seems to look for the standby first and this is the log I get:

```
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:19999
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::19999
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3 (tataraboshi)
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0



2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  setting backend node 0 status to NODE DOWN
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host 192.168.2.114(5432)
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failover: no valid backends node found
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  Restart all children
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  execute command: /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/failover.sh 0 0 "" ""
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13335: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 3

+ FALLING_NODE=0
+ OLDPRIMARY_NODE=0
+ NEW_PRIMARY=
+ PGDATA=
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ su postgres -c 'ssh -T postgres@ touch /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/failover.trigger'
^C
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
+ exit 0
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node_repeatedly: waiting for finding a primary node
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0

2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 1

2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  shutdown request. closing listen socket
[root(at)URTTDFDB01 ~]# pgpool -n
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  reading status file: 0 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:19999
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::19999
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3 (tataraboshi)
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0

2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:19999
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::19999
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3 (tataraboshi)
2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0

2021-12-29 16:43:56: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failed to connect to PostgreSQL server on "192.168.2.114:5432", getsockopt() detected error "Operation now in progress"
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: ERROR:  failed to make persistent db connection
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: DETAIL:  connection to host:"192.168.2.114:5432" failed
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  setting backend node 0 status to NODE DOWN
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host 192.168.2.114(5432)
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  failover: no valid backends node found
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  Restart all children
2021-12-29 16:44:08: pid 13334: LOG:  execute command: /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/failover.sh 0 0 "" ""
+ FALLING_NODE=0
+ OLDPRIMARY_NODE=0
+ NEW_PRIMARY=
+ PGDATA=
+ '[' 0 = 0 ']'
+ '[' 0 -eq 0 ']'
+ su postgres -c 'ssh -T postgres@ touch /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/failover.trigger'
^C
Session terminated, killing shell... ...killed.
+ exit 0
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node_repeatedly: waiting for finding a primary node
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 1

2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2021-12-29 16:44:34: pid 13334: LOG:  shutdown request. closing listen socket
[root(at)URTTDFDB01 ~]# pgpool -n
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  reading status file: 0 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  reading status file: 1 th backend is set to down status
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  Setting up socket for 0.0.0.0:19999
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  Setting up socket for :::19999
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  pgpool-II successfully started. version 3.4.3 (tataraboshi)
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  find_primary_node: checking backend no 0



2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  find_primary_node: primary node id is 0
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: ERROR:  failed to authenticate
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: DETAIL:  invalid authentication message response type, Expecting 'R' and received 'E'
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  setting backend node 1 status to NODE DOWN
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  starting degeneration. shutdown host 192.168.2.104(5432)
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  Restart all children
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  execute command: /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/failover.sh 1 0 192.168.2.114 /var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13491: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 3
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13492: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 3
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13493: LOG:  child process received shutdown request signal 3
+ FALLING_NODE=1
+ OLDPRIMARY_NODE=0
+ NEW_PRIMARY=192.168.2.114
+ PGDATA=/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/
+ '[' 1 = 0 ']'
+ exit 0
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  failover: set new primary node: 0
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  failover: set new master node: 0
failover done. shutdown host 192.168.2.104(5432)2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13490: LOG:  failover done. shutdown host 192.168.2.104(5432)
2021-12-29 16:47:19: pid 13495: LOG:  worker process received restart request
2021-12-29 16:47:20: pid 13494: LOG:  restart request received in pcp child process
2021-12-29 16:47:20: pid 13490: LOG:  PCP child 13494 exits with status 256 in failover()
```

So there is some kind of authentication issue but only for the standby server (and it's not dependant on the physical server.. if I switch master and standby it still happens on new standby)?  Any ideas on what might be going on here?  Thanks.

```
Pgsql: 9.45
Pgpool: 3.4.3
```

Here are the relevant parts of my pgpool.conf config:

```
# - pgpool Connection Settings -



listen_addresses = '*'
                                   # Host name or IP address to listen on:
                                   # '*' for all, '' for no TCP/IP connections
                                   # (change requires restart)
port = 19999
                                   # Port number
                                   # (change requires restart)
socket_dir = '/tmp'
                                   # Unix domain socket path
                                   # The Debian package defaults to
                                   # /var/run/postgresql
                                   # (change requires restart)



# - Backend Connection Settings -



backend_hostname0 = '192.168.2.114'
                                   # Host name or IP address to connect to for backend 0
backend_port0 = 5432
                                   # Port number for backend 0
backend_weight0 = 1
                                   # Weight for backend 0 (only in load balancing mode)
backend_data_directory0 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/'
                                   # Data directory for backend 0
backend_flag0 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'
                                   # Controls various backend behavior
                                   # ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER or DISALLOW_TO_FAILOVER
backend_hostname1 = '192.168.2.104'
backend_port1 = 5432
backend_weight1 = 1
backend_data_directory1 = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/data/'
backend_flag1 = 'ALLOW_TO_FAILOVER'



# - Authentication -



enable_pool_hba = off
                                   # Use pool_hba.conf for client authentication
pool_passwd = ''
                                   # File name of pool_passwd for md5 authentication.
                                   # "" disables pool_passwd.
                                   # (change requires restart)
authentication_timeout = 60
                                   # Delay in seconds to complete client authentication
                                   # 0 means no timeout.



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# LOAD BALANCING MODE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



load_balance_mode = off
                                   # Activate load balancing mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
ignore_leading_white_space = on
                                   # Ignore leading white spaces of each query
white_function_list = ''
                                   # Comma separated list of function names
                                   # that don't write to database
                                   # Regexp are accepted
black_function_list = 'currval,lastval,nextval,setval'
                                   # Comma separated list of function names
                                   # that write to database
                                   # Regexp are accepted



database_redirect_preference_list = ''
                                                                                                                                   # comma separated list of pairs of database and node id.
                                                                                                                                   # example: postgres:primary,mydb[0-4]:1,mydb[5-9]:2'
                                                                                                                                   # valid for streaming replicaton mode only.



app_name_redirect_preference_list = ''
                                                                                                                                   # comma separated list of pairs of app name and node id.
                                                                                                                                   # example: 'psql:primary,myapp[0-4]:1,myapp[5-9]:standby'
                                                                                                                                   # valid for streaming replicaton mode only.
allow_sql_comments = off
                                                                                                                                   # if on, ignore SQL comments when judging if load balance or
                                                                                                                                   # query cache is possible.
                                                                                                                                   # If off, SQL comments effectively prevent the judgment
                                                                                                                                   # (pre 3.4 behavior).



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# MASTER/SLAVE MODE
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



master_slave_mode = on
                                   # Activate master/slave mode
                                   # (change requires restart)
master_slave_sub_mode = 'stream'
                                   # Master/slave sub mode
                                   # Valid values are combinations slony or
                                   # stream. Default is slony.
                                   # (change requires restart)



# - Streaming -



sr_check_period = 0
                                   # Streaming replication check period
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
sr_check_user = 'postgres'
                                   # Streaming replication check user
                                   # This is neccessary even if you disable streaming
                                   # replication delay check by sr_check_period = 0
sr_check_password = ''
                                   # Password for streaming replication check user
delay_threshold = 10000000
                                   # Threshold before not dispatching query to standby node
                                   # Unit is in bytes
                                   # Disabled (0) by default



# - Special commands -



follow_master_command = ''
                                   # Executes this command after master failover
                                   # Special values:
                                   #   %d = node id
                                   #   %h = host name
                                   #   %p = port number
                                   #   %D = database cluster path
                                   #   %m = new master node id
                                   #   %H = hostname of the new master node
                                   #   %M = old master node id
                                   #   %P = old primary node id
                                                                                                                                   #   %r = new master port number
                                                                                                                                   #   %R = new master database cluster path
                                   #   %% = '%' character



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# HEALTH CHECK
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



health_check_period = 2
                                   # Health check period
                                   # Disabled (0) by default
health_check_timeout = 10
                                   # Health check timeout
                                   # 0 means no timeout
health_check_user = 'postgres'
                                   # Health check user
health_check_password = 'P0stgres'
                                   # Password for health check user
health_check_max_retries = 0
                                   # Maximum number of times to retry a failed health check before giving up.
health_check_retry_delay = 1
                                   # Amount of time to wait (in seconds) between retries.
connect_timeout = 10000
                                   # Timeout value in milliseconds before giving up to connect to backend.
                                                                                                                                   # Default is 10000 ms (10 second). Flaky network user may want to increase
                                                                                                                                   # the value. 0 means no timeout.
                                                                                                                                   # Note that this value is not only used for health check,
                                                                                                                                   # but also for ordinary conection to backend.



#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# FAILOVER AND FAILBACK
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



failover_command = '/var/lib/pgsql/9.4/failover.sh %d %P %H %R'

failback_command = ''

                                                                                                                                   #   %R = new master database cluster path
                                   #   %% = '%' character



fail_over_on_backend_error = on




search_primary_node_timeout = 10




#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WATCHDOG
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------



# - Enabling -



use_watchdog = off
                                    # Activates watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)



# -Connection to up stream servers -



trusted_servers = ''

ping_path = '/bin'




wd_hostname = ''

wd_port = 9000

wd_authkey = ''




# - Virtual IP control Setting -



delegate_IP = ''

ifconfig_path = '/sbin'
                                    # ifconfig command path
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_up_cmd = 'ifconfig eth1:0 inet $_IP_$ netmask 255.255.255.0'
                                    # startup delegate IP command
                                    # (change requires restart)
if_down_cmd = 'ifconfig eth1:0 down'
                                    # shutdown delegate IP command
                                    # (change requires restart)



arping_path = '/usr/sbin'           # arping command path
                                    # (change requires restart)



arping_cmd = 'arping -U -I eth1 $_IP_$ -w 1'
                                    # arping command
                                    # (change requires restart)



# - Behaivor on escalation Setting -



clear_memqcache_on_escalation = on
                                    # Clear all the query cache on shared memory
                                    # when standby pgpool escalate to active pgpool
                                    # (= virtual IP holder).
                                    # This should be off if client connects to pgpool
                                    # not using virtual IP.
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_escalation_command = ''
                                    # Executes this command at escalation on new active pgpool.
                                    # (change requires restart)



# - Lifecheck Setting -



# -- common --



wd_lifecheck_method = 'heartbeat'
                                    # Method of watchdog lifecheck ('heartbeat' or 'query')
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_interval = 10
                                    # lifecheck interval (sec) > 0
                                    # (change requires restart)



# -- heartbeat mode --



wd_heartbeat_port = 9694
                                    # Port number for receiving heartbeat signal
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_heartbeat_keepalive = 2
                                    # Interval time of sending heartbeat signal (sec)
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_heartbeat_deadtime = 30
                                    # Deadtime interval for heartbeat signal (sec)
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_destination0 = 'host0_ip1'
                                    # Host name or IP address of destination 0
                                    # for sending heartbeat signal.
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_destination_port0 = 9694
                                    # Port number of destination 0 for sending
                                    # heartbeat signal. Usually this is the
                                    # same as wd_heartbeat_port.
                                    # (change requires restart)
heartbeat_device0 = ''
                                    # Name of NIC device (such like 'eth0')
                                    # used for sending/receiving heartbeat
                                    # signal to/from destination 0.
                                    # This works only when this is not empty
                                    # and pgpool has root privilege.
                                    # (change requires restart)



#heartbeat_destination1 = 'host0_ip2'
#heartbeat_destination_port1 = 9694
#heartbeat_device1 = ''



# -- query mode --



wd_life_point = 3
                                    # lifecheck retry times
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_query = 'SELECT 1'
                                    # lifecheck query to pgpool from watchdog
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_dbname = 'template1'
                                    # Database name connected for lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_user = 'nobody'
                                    # watchdog user monitoring pgpools in lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)
wd_lifecheck_password = ''
                                    # Password for watchdog user in lifecheck
                                    # (change requires restart)
 
# - Other pgpool Connection Settings -



#other_pgpool_hostname0 = 'host0'
                                    # Host name or IP address to connect to for other pgpool 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
#other_pgpool_port0 = 5432
                                    # Port number for othet pgpool 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
#other_wd_port0 = 9000
                                    # Port number for othet watchdog 0
                                    # (change requires restart)
#other_pgpool_hostname1 = 'host1'
#other_pgpool_port1 = 5432
#other_wd_port1 = 9000
```

Answer (score 2):

We faced this issue with pgpool 4.3.3 anda 4.4.2 versions. May be this solution can help someone;
first stop the pgpool
than remove /tmp/pgpool_status file
and start the pgpool again.
Pgpool_status file can be found in a different directory.